# "No such file or directory" running dynamically linked executable in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install [AFDKO](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html) on Ubuntu. After installation I added environmental variables also. But when I call the command

```
$ makeotfexe
```

It returns

```
bash: /home/randika/FDK/Tools/linux/makeotfexe: No such file or directory
```

But when I "cd" in to that folder in above path the file exists and can be accessed and opened. What is issue here? How can I correct it?

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: What does `file /home/randika/FDK/Tools/linux/makeotfexe` show?

Comment: Smacks self - your right. Nuking it.

Comment: @Barmar 
`/home/randika/FDK/Tools/linux/makeotfexe: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=1baf3671d77c1a1cff4861acbe6c41ad57be7b03, not stripped`

Comment: Did you actually type the `$` before `makeotfexe`, or is that your shell prompt?

Comment: No I didn't type `$`in front of makeotfexe. I just typed `makeotfexe`.

Comment: Likely it depends on a shared library that doesn't exist. Check the output of `ldd /path/to/your-executable`. Certainly not a bash question, by the way -- bash just tells the operating system to execute the file; the error you're getting is from the operating system refusing to do so; you'd get it with any shell, or any non-shell program trying to do the same `execve` call.

Comment: This is indeed duplicative of several questions on unix.stackexchange.com; see for instance http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are trying to run a 32bit executable in a 64bit environment. Try installing ia32-libs package.